# Python Regular Expression loop

Tags: python, regex, search, loops, findall

I have this code wich will look for certain things in a file. The file looks like this:

```
name;lastname;job;5465465
name2;lastname2;job2;5465465
name3;lastname3;job3;5465465
```

This is the python code:

```
import re
import sys

filehandle = open('somefile.csv', 'r')
text = filehandle.read()
b = re.search("([a-zA-Z]+);([a-z\sA-Z]+);([a-zA-Z]*);([0-9^-]+)\n?",text)
print (b.group(2),b.group(1),b.group(3),b.group(4))
```

no it will only print:

```
lastname;name;job;5465465
```

It supposed to print the lastname first so i did that with groups. Now i need a loop to print all lines like this:

```
lastname;name;job;5465465
lastname2;name2;job2;5465465
lastname3;name3;job3;5465465l
```

i tried all kind of loops but it doesnt go trough the whole file... how do i need to do this?

it must be done with the re module. I know its easy in the csv module ;)

Comment: Why do you need to use re? Well, you can use split to split by semicolon, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process the file line by line.

```
import re
import sys

with open('somefile.csv', 'r') as filehandle:
    for text in filehandle:
        b = re.search("([a-zA-Z]+);([a-z\sA-Z]+);([a-zA-Z]*);([0-9^-]+)\n?",text)
        print (b.group(2),b.group(1),b.group(3),b.group(4))
```

Your file has nicely semi-colon separated values, so it would be easier to just use `split` or the csv library as has been suggested.

Comment: Welcome. Just bear in mind that there are easier ways to do this than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `re`, but a good job for `csv`:

```
import csv
with open('somefile.csv', 'r') as f:
    for rec in csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'):
        print (rec[1], rec[0], rec[2], rec[3])
```

You can use `re` if you want to check the validity of individual elements (valid phone number, no numbers in name, capitalized names, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The fault is not with the loops, but rather with your regex / capture group patterns. The class [a-zA-Z]+ will not match "lastname3" or "lastname2". This sample works:

```
import re
import sys

for line in open('somefile.csv', 'r'):
    b = re.search("(\w+);(\w+);(\w*);([0-9^-]+)\n?",line)
    if b:
        print "%s;%s;%s;%s" % (b.group(2),b.group(1),b.group(3),b.group(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you just want to reorder what you have, in which case I don't know whether regex are needed.  I believe the following might be of use:

reorder = operator.itemgetter(1, 0, 2, 3)

http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any sense.